# Model Manager; TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to test a method within a custom model manager `by_week()`. Upon debugging it, I've come across an issue of trying to query all objects within the method with `profile.questions.all()` and `self.model.objects.all()` where self.model is the `Question` model. Yet both raise the following error: `*** TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`. Why is this error being raised?

As background info: I created test data by creating instances through the admin interface and dumped everything in the database into a JSON file.

*models.py*

```
class QuestionSearchManager(Manager):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def by_week(self, profile):
        # today = datetime.date.today()
        # weekago = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        questions = self.model.objects.all()
        user_tags = profile.questions.all()
        x = self.model.objects.filter(
            tags__name__in=user_tags
        )
        return x


class Post(Model):

    body = TextField()
    date = DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    comment = ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    profile = ForeignKey(
        'authors.Profile', on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True,
        related_name='%(class)ss',
        related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )
    score = GenericRelation(
        'Vote', related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )


    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Question(Post):

    title = CharField(max_length=75)
    tags = ManyToManyField(
        'Tag', related_name="questions", related_query_name="question"
    )
    objects = Manager()
    postings = QuestionSearchManager()
```

*python manage.py shell*

```
>>> from authors.models import Profile
>>> p = Profile.objects.get(id=2)
>>> p.questions.all()
<QuerySet [<Question: Question object (13)>]>
>>> from posts.models import Question
>>> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Question: Question object (9)>, <Question: Question object (10)>, <Question: Question object (11)>, <Question: Question object (12)>, <Question: Question object (13)>, <Question: Question object (14)>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your above example, the `questions` object is never used. But as a side note, instead of `self.model.objects.all()` you probably want to use `self.get_queryset()` to query the model which is being managed by the manager, then use that to filter the questions.

Something like

```py
    questions = self.get_queryset()
    user_tags = profile.questions.all()
    x = questions.filter(
        tags__name__in=user_tags
    )
```

The error you're seeing is confusing because what is happening is that you're invoking the custom `__getattr__`, which in turn is using `isinstance` with bad arguments. The type of the items given to `tags__name__in=` must match that of the `tags__name` field. Presumably, strings, not `Question` instances.

So, the fix would be to fix the value of `user_tags` to match the type expected for `tags__name`.

Comment: To address `questions = self.get_queryset()`, it still raises the same TypeError.

Comment: @binny please update the question with the full traceback and I'll review again.

Comment: It silently assigns the error to `answer`. There is no automatic traceback output. 

```-> answer = self.get_queryset()
(Pdb) answer
*** TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
(Pdb)
```

Comment: @binny Please make sure your question contains the actual code that's causing your problem. I'm not able to reproduce that behavior based on what is in the question.